# wordpress Custom search page returning all post type

Tags: php, wordpress

have written a custom wordpress search template and wish to retrieve only 'post' type posts and not any page or any custom post type.

The issue is that the query is returning all posts type (and pages) .. following is the query arguments .

```
$pageContent = new WP_query();
$pageContent->query(array('s'=> $query, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'post'));
```

Another issue (not very important at the moment), the next_posts_link() and previous_posts_link() do not seem to show any link for pagination as well.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that there is a filter customizing the query?

Comment: @lkke not sure .. am not well versed in wordpress. kindly assist if there is any way to check or override if it is so

Comment: Typically in `functions.php` or in a plugin. Look for function calls to `add_filter('pre_get_posts', ..)`.

Comment: Check your generated query by using echo $pageContent->request; and look what condition does wp_posts.post_type has

Comment: @user850010 post type does include other post types as well.

Comment: @ikke cannot seem to find the 'pre_get_posts' in functions.php . is there any way to overwrite it..

Comment: I'm just guessing here but try putting wp_reset_query(); before $pageContent = new WP_query();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution by adding the above mentioned filter and doing the following:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');

function SearchFilter($query) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'post');
        return $query;
    }
```

Thank you for all the time :) ..